# Android Gradle update to 6.2.2 NoSuchMethodError with DeprecationLogger.nagUserWith

Tags: android

When I update in an Android project Gradle to `6.2.2` from `6.1.1` I run into this non-understandable error.

```
 > Configure project :commonLib
The BuildListener.buildStarted(Gradle) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#apis_buildlistener_buildstarted_and_gradle_buildstarted_have_been_deprecated
    at build_bpg7owlpe9pidz38268q3rf54.run(/builds/cross/mxtracks/commonLib/build.gradle:1)
    (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
Internal API constructor DefaultDomainObjectSet(Class<T>) has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use ObjectFactory.domainObjectSet(Class<T>) instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#domainobjectset for more details.
    at build_bpg7owlpe9pidz38268q3rf54.run(/builds/cross/mxtracks/commonLib/build.gradle:1)
    (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
> Configure project :MXApp
Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':MXApp'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.util.DeprecationLogger.nagUserWith(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'paidRelease' not found.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
```

I'm out of ideas, even

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    android.ndkVersion '21.0.6113669'
}
```

shows the same result. Maybe someone can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason, running the gradle task with `--stacktrace` helps me to find the reason. 
It was [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) and this release [2.7.5](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/releases/tag/2.7.5) solved it finally

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This just resolved my issue.